# How to create a layer with only the isolated pixels using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, pixel

I have a raster (with one band) of a land and there is some islands surrounded by No Data.

I would like to create a layer consisting only with these isolated small groups of pixels (group maximum size of 4 pixels).

How can I do this in QGIS?

This is my map of the sea of Philippines. I'd like a layer only with the small islands.

[image: map of the Sea of Philippines]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your raster is'nt very large you can use a vectorized approach:

1. Convert the raster pixels to polygons with **Raster pixels to polygons**
2. **Dissolve**, no Dissolve Field and Keep Disjoint Features Separate=Yes in Advanced options.
3. **Extract by expression**. My pixel size is 10*10 m, so to get four pixels or less I use the expression: `$area<=400`
4. Optional: **Rasterize** the output polygons.

[image]

[image]